# Descargar imágenes en diferentes formatos indicados en un select

Tags: javascript, html

He montado un `<select>` con tres formatos diferentes de imágenes para que los usuarios las puedan descargar.

El problema está en que me las abre en la misma página y mi intención es que, o bien salga directamente la opción de descargar, o bien las abra en otra pestaña.

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
    <select id="filename-Strands-Logo"  class="select-download">
        <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.jpg">JPG</option>
        <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.png">PNG</option>
        <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.svg">SVG</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href=document.getElementById('filename-Strands-Logo').value" value="Download" class="green-btn-download"/>
```

Lo he intentado también con jQuery, pero tampoco me funciona.

Ésta es la página donde podéis ver a lo que me refiero:

- https://strands.com/company/press-kit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer el trabajo de diferentes maneras.

Una de ellas, manteniendo todo el código que tienes del formulario, podría ser haciendo los siguientes cambios:

- Agregar `formulario.action = filename_Strands_Logo.value` al atributo `onsubmit` del formulario.
- Cambiar el atributo `target` del formulario a `_blank` para que se abra en una nueva pestaña o ventana.
- Cambiar el tipo del `<input>` de `button` a `submit` para que provoque el envío del formulario al pulsar en él.

Aquí tienes el ejemplo funcionando (saldrá un mensaje de advertencia en la consola de depuración indicando que no se puede abrir un elemento emergente desde el `iframe` del entorno de pruebas):

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="form.action = filename_Strands_Logo.value" target="_blank">
  <select id="filename_Strands_Logo" class="select-download">
    <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.jpg">JPG</option>
    <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.png">PNG</option>
    <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.svg">SVG</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Download" class="green-btn-download"/>
</form>
```

Te recomiendo que uses identificadores que no incluyan el carácter `-` para poder usarlos de manera directa en JavaScript evitándote hacer un `getElementById()`.

---

También podrías haberlo hecho más parecido a tu solución de la siguiente manera:

```html
<select id="filename_Strands_Logo" class="select-download">
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.jpg">JPG</option>
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.png">PNG</option>
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.svg">SVG</option>
</select>
<a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="this.href = filename_Strands_Logo.value">
  <button>Download</button>
</a>
```

Como puedes comprobar he cambiado el `<input type="button">` por un `<button>` que está contenido en un enlace `<a>` con la propiedad `target` configurada en `_blank`, por lo que al ser pulsado abrirá el enlace en una nueva pestaña o ventana.

---

Existen infinidad de maneras de hacer lo que deseas, como te han indicando en otras respuestas. Existe otra genérica que te facilitará repetir el componente tantas veces como necesites:

```js
/* Buscamos todos los elementos con "data-boton-id" */
document.querySelectorAll("[data-boton-id]").forEach((elem) => {
  /* Por cada botón agregamos un manipulador del clic */
  elem.addEventListener("click", function(evento) {
    /* Obtenemos la URL seleccionada en el select cuya ID está en data-boton-id */
    const url = window[evento.target.dataset.botonId]?.value;
    /* Si existe dicho identificador, nos vamos a la URL elegida */
    if (url !== undefined) {
      /* Mostramos información de depuración en la consola */
      console.log(
        "Id:",
        evento.target.dataset.botonId,
        ", Visitamos:",
        url
      );
      window.open(url, "_blank");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="uno">
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.jpg">JPG</option>
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.png">PNG</option>
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.svg">SVG</option>
</select>
<button data-boton-id="uno">Download 1</button>
<hr/>
<select id="dos">
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.jpg">JPG</option>
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.png">PNG</option>
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.svg">SVG</option>
</select>
<button data-boton-id="dos">Download 2</button>
<hr/>
<select id="tres">
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.jpg">JPG</option>
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.png">PNG</option>
  <option value="https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo.svg">SVG</option>
</select>
<button data-boton-id="tres">Download 3</button>
```

De esta manera con una única función JavaSCript podrás agregar tantos botones como desees que te lleven a diferentes URLs.

Answer (score 0):

De momento lo he solucionado modificando la linea del input

```
 <input type="button" onclick="window.open(document.getElementById('filename-Strands-Logo', '_blank').value)" value="Download" class="green-btn-download"/>
```

De todas formas, si alguien tiene la forma de poder hacer download directamente, le quedo muy agradecido.

Un cordial saludo,
Juanma

Answer (score 0):

Con `jQuery` se me ocurre pasar el atributo `href` de forma dinámica a una etiqueta `<a>` que envuelva a tu botón y agregarle el atributo `download`. De esta manera debería descargar la imagen con la extensión que el usuario elija *(siempre y cuando exista en la ruta)*.

Si no es para descargar, la puedes abrir en otra pestaña del navegador cambiando el atributo `download` por `target="_blank"`.

El código está comentado, pero si te quedan dudas, déjalas en los comentarios. El snippet no te va a descargar la imagen, pero puedes probar en tu sitio.

```js
//Detectar el evento change del select
$('#filename-Strands-Logo').on('change', function (){
  //Capturar el value seleccionado
 let extension = $(this).val();
 //Validar que no venga el value vacío
 if(extension != ''){
  //Concatena la extensión a la ruta fija del archivo y agrega el atributo href a la etiqueta <a>
  $("a").attr("href", "https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Strands-Logo." + extension);
 } else {
  //Si el value llega vacío, elimina el atributo href a la etiqueta <a> y muestra un alerta al usuario
  $("a").removeAttr("href");
  alert('Debes seleccionar al menos una extensión');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Debes tener un option vacío para que jquery detecte el evento change del select-->
<select id="filename-Strands-Logo" class="select-download">
  <option value="">Selecciona una extensión</option>
  <option value="jpg">JPG</option>
  <option value="png">PNG</option>
  <option value="svg">SVG</option>
</select>

<!-- A la etiqueta <a> no le seteas el atributo href ya que será dinámico y le agregas el atributo download para que se descargue la imagen -->
<a download>
  <input type="button" value="Download" class="green-btn-download"/>
</a>
```